# facing difficulties converting utc timezone to local

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am getting date and time like this

```
date_time =  "2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374"
```

And to convert these to AM, PM format I am doing something like this

```
date_formate = datetime.fromisoformat(date_time).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
```

but End time I am getting is in not local time seems it's in UTC , I am trying to convert it in utc but no luck doing something like this

```
dtUTC = datetime.fromisoformat(date_formate[:-1])
dtZone = dtUTC.astimezone()
print(dtZone.isoformat(timespec='seconds'))
```

got this solution on stackoverflow but **getting error  Invalid isoformat string: '2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374'**

Comment: The first line is not valid Python.

Comment: @ScottHunter how? it is string I am passing

Comment: Could you please clarify: `date_time` represents UTC and you want local time? Or the other way around? Also, this should have nothing to do with am/pm vs. 24h format, no?

Comment: But it was not a string in your posted code.

Comment: I get the following error using Python 3.8.10: `module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromisoformat'`

Comment: @ScottHunter use the datetime class instead of the module, `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: @FObersteiner  end result I want is in AM/PM but in local time zone with my this time '2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374'

Comment: My question was if  '2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374' is UTC or already your local time.

Comment: @FObersteiner it's in UTC .

Comment: @FObersteiner  I am doing this in javascript and it's getting desired result   `moment.utc(dateTime).local().format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python assumes local time by default if you don't specify a time zone / UTC offset. So in this case, you need to set UTC first, then convert, then format (if you want a string as output):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

date_time =  "2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374" # UTC is not specified here...

local = datetime.fromisoformat(date_time).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone()
print(local) # my tz was on UTC+1 at that date...
# 2022-02-17 09:29:36.345374+01:00

local_formatted = local.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
print(local_formatted)
# 17/02/2022 09:29 AM
```

If `astimezone(None)` does not work, you can try [tzlocal](https://pypi.org/project/tzlocal/);

```py
import tzlocal
zone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
local = datetime.fromisoformat(date_time).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(zone)
local_formatted = local.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
print(local_formatted)
# 17/02/2022 09:29 AM
```

or derive a timezone object from a timedelta, e.g.

```py
from datetime import timedelta
zone = timezone(timedelta(minutes=-300)) # UTC-5 hours
local = datetime.fromisoformat(date_time).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(zone)
local_formatted = local.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p')
print(local_formatted)
# 17/02/2022 03:29 AM
```

Comment: thanks for replying sir , I applied  this alog on this date `2022-04-01 09:56:27.432`  my expected output is   `01/04/2022 02:56 PM`  while I am getting this  `01/04/2022 09:56 AM`   .

Comment: @voicenob then your machine runs on UTC. What time zone do you want?

Comment: my timezone is `-300` written . can I manage this thing from this function ?